# Why when I try to print all prime numbers below 10 the number 4 is also printed with them?

Tags: java, primes

I am trying to create a program that adds up all the prime numbers up to a certain amount. While I was building my program I came across a problem. Whenever i try to print all prime numbers below 10 it prints them out and also 4.I can't figure out for the love of me why 4 is being printed out. Can you guys help me solve this problem?

My code here:

```
private static boolean isPrime = false;
private static int sum = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    addPrimeNumbers();
}


private static void addPrimeNumbers(){
    for(int n = 2; n < 10; n++){
        if(checkIfPrime(n)){
            System.out.println(n); // here it prints out all odds numbers below 10 and 4 
            sum += n;
        }
    }
}

private static boolean checkIfPrime(int potentialPrimeNumbeer) {
    for (int i = 2; i < potentialPrimeNumbeer / 2; i++) {
        if (potentialPrimeNumbeer % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
5
7
```

Comment: Why are you calling method `checkIfPrime` if it's to test oddness? Shouldn't it just `return potentialPrimeNumbeer % 2 != 0;`

Comment: What my thinking is checkprime is supposed to get n which is in the addPrimeNumbers and while addPrimeNumbers loop is happening it takes the variable n and gives it to checkIfPrime so it can check if n is prime or not. Does this make sense?

Comment: Nine is not prime but is odd, so I'm still confused.

Comment: were did you get 9 from?

Comment: *Why when I try to print all odd numbers below 10* Nine is an odd number less than ten.

Comment: OH that's my mistake. I meant all prime numbers. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `checkIfPrime()` the `for`-loop has the condition

```
i < potentialPrimeNumbeer / 2
```

With `i = 2` and `potentialPrimeNumbeer = 4` this is `2 < 2` which is false. Therefore the `for`-loop is never executed and `checkIfPrime()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= potentialPrimeNumbeer / 2; i++)
```

greater than or equal to will work because now you will enter the loop. Otherwise all for loop conditions are not met, it does not enter the loop and True is returned.

Answer (score 2):

You meant to test less than equal to (not just less than), however you can improve on your algorithm by unrolling the first test (divisibility by two). Then you can start with three and increment by two values on each iteration (halving your runtime). We can further optimize it by stopping at values less than or equal to the square root of `potentialPrimeNumber` - which further reduces the number of test cases. That leaves,

```
private static boolean checkIfPrime(int potentialPrimeNumber) {
    if (potentialPrimeNumber == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (potentialPrimeNumber % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(potentialPrimeNumber); i += 2) {
        if (potentialPrimeNumber % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```